# Segmantation Fault - C using malloc

Tags: malloc

I'm trying to allocate memory for array of pointers to object.
ObjectP is a pointer to struct named Object.
before that function, I declare on array as: ObjectP* array. So array is pointer to array of pointers to object.
Then I send &array so I'll have a pointer to that.
Say my table_size is 2. I get Segmentation fault when I try to enter *array[1]=NULL.
What is the problem?

This is my code:

```
    void allocateArrayMemory(ObjectP** array,size_t table_size)
    {
    *array=(ObjectP*)malloc(table_size*sizeof(ObjectP));
    int i=0;
    for (i = 0; i < (int)table_size; ++i)
    {
        *array[i]=NULL;
        printf("%d\n",i);
    }
    printf("finished allocating\n");
    if(*array==NULL)
    {
        printf("null\n");
    }

    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and adjust the formatting.

Comment: Try `(*array)[i]=NULL;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `*array[i]=NULL;` is acting like `*(array[i])=NULL;` and what you want is `(*array)[i]=NULL;`.

When i=1, `*(array[i])` dereferences the `struct Object ***` that follows the `struct Object ***` you passed in to allocateArrayMemory, while `(*array)[i]`  dereferences the second `struct Object **` in the freshly-malloced memory area.

Some notes:

1. Fix the spelling of 'Segmentation' in title.
2. Test the result of malloc before using.  In your code, you have a test after using *array; move it up.
3. I suggest using `memset(*array, 0, table_size*sizeof(ObjectP));` instead of a loop to initialize *array.
4. It's bad form in C to cast the malloc result.  Instead just say `*array = malloc(table_size*sizeof(ObjectP));`.
5. As a matter of style, I'd have allocateArrayMemory be a function that returns the address of allocated memory, instead of via parameter.  For example:

   `ObjectP* allocateArrayMemory(size_t table_size) {`

   `ObjectP *array = malloc(table_size*sizeof(ObjectP));`

   ...

   `if(array==NULL) { printf ...; return NULL; }`

   ...

   `for (i=0; i < table_size; ++i)`

   ```
   {
   ```

   `array[i] = NULL;`

   ...

   ```
   }
   ```

   ...

   `return array;`

and in the caller,  `ObjectP *a;` ... `a = allocateArrayMemory(6);`.